# the system controllability and observability

Tags: linear-control

If a linear system is controllable, does it mean we can find  the control standard form in state space, but it doesn't mean all the forms of state space representations is controllable?

Comment: Better ask it on electrical stackexchange. your question is related to control system engineering

Comment: Controllability has a precise, formal, mathematical meaning, so it is on-topic here in my opinion. However, I still don't understand the question. Especially the last part simply doesn't make sense to me as an English sentence. @孙志鹏 please reword it and add some details as well.